# Android - running command line program compiled with CCTools

Tags: android, c++, command-line, terminal

I know this is asked before maybe many times; but I could not find a proper answer. Anyhow,

On my Android phone, I have installed CCTools. I can compile C/C++ programs and run them using the CCTools menu items. But, when I try to run the program from the Terminal, I get 'permission denied'. I use Linux style './a.out' to run.

Answer (score 0):

tl.dr.: Android is not a good platform for the development of command line applications.

For security reasons, Android doesn't support executing files from the user storage. This is done by the `noexec` mount flag. This can't be changed, because the underlying file system doesn't support executables. (At least on my Nexus 5 with Lollipop. You can try (if you have root) with `mount -o remount,exec /storage/[your sdcard path]`. The path can be found in the output of `mount`)

As a hack, if you have root, you can copy the file to /mnt/obb/. This is a temporary filesystem. There you have to do `chmod 0755 /mnt/obb/[filename]` to mark the file as executable. Then you can execute it.

Comment: Thank you. But, how the CCTools runs the command line application?

Comment: CCTools copies the file into a cache director, which allows executable files. There the file is marked as executable and then executed. It's the same as my hack, but with another directory. You can see the implementation in [`LauncherConsoleActivity.java`](https://code.google.com/p/cctools/source/browse/trunk/cctools/src/com/pdaxrom/cctools/LauncherConsoleActivity.java) in OnCreate

Comment: I see. Do you know the C++ way of doing this?

Comment: Using QT,  and QDir class I could get the temporary folder. I think I can copy the file there and execute.

Comment: To run a binary file on Android you should put it in the /data/local/ directory and make it executable. You might also need to start the adbd daemon daemon with root permissions.